# How to modify original dataframe after updating its value off of a filtered view/subset of rows from the original dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe "df" that contains:

```
SPORT, NAME, TEST 
Tennis, A, TESTA
Tennis, B, TESTB
Basketball, C, TESTC
Volleyball, D, TESTC
```

I want to change the 'TEST' column only for the ones where SPORT == 'Tennis' to 'CHANGED'. I tried the following:

```
tennislist = df[df['SPORT'] == 'Tennis']
tennislist['TEST'] = 'CHANGED'
```

While tennislist appears to be updated with the correct values, when I then print out the original "df", I see no changes at all. How can I make it so that even though I filtered on tennislist to update the column 'TEST' that those changes also updates the original "df" that I filtered from?

Comment: what is the reason for creating `tennislist` as a separate object instead of modifying `df` directly?

Comment: I just wanted to be able to apply something like an iterrows. Theres way too much data in this dataframe and I want to just iterate and apply processing on a row by row basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the values in df with

```
df.loc[df['SPORT'].eq('Tennis'), 'TEST'] = 'CHANGED'
```

Your code is currently creating a new object called `tennislist` which is a subset of the rows in `df`, but if you change `tennislist` it will not be reflected in `df`.